# Set background from value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td><a style="display:none" color="#ff00cc" title="t">t</a><a color="blue" title="asas">a</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td><a style="display:none" color="#6600cc" title="t">t</a><a color="blue" title="asas">a</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td><td><a style="display:none" color="#00ccff" title="t">t</a><a color="blue" title="asas">a</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

How can i with jQuery set background-color for whole current TR? I must get color from last TD, from selector a (non visible), from parameter color, where title = 't'.
Thanks for help!

http://jsfiddle.net/QaC9w/1/

I would like receive:

http://jsfiddle.net/QaC9w/2/

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You seemed to have linked to an empty JS fiddle. We're not going to do your work for you.

Comment: i would like receive: http://jsfiddle.net/QaC9w/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a[title="t"]').each(function() { // the <a> you want to look at
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr'); // the tr of this <a>
    tr.css({
        backgroundColor: $(this).attr('color') // set the color based on the <a>
    });
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/QaC9w/6/

Comment: thanks, but this working bad: http://jsfiddle.net/QaC9w/3/ . I would like receive: http://jsfiddle.net/QaC9w/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it should work:

```
$(this).closest('tr').css('background-color','your color');
```

Comment: but how to get current color?

Comment: Something like this: var color=$(this).closest('tr').("td:last").css('color');